# Sorted by value HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap `HashMap<String, List<OtherModel>>` - I need to sort by the field of the first `List<OtherModel>` element, have any ideas?)

I have incorrect code for example:

```
 public static HashMap<String, List<AsoInfoModel>> sortAsoByValue(HashMap<String, List<AsoInfoModel>> items) {
        List<Map.Entry<String, List<AsoInfoModel>>> list = new LinkedList<>(items.entrySet());
        list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue::AsoInfoModel::position, Comparator.naturalOrder());

        HashMap<String, List<AsoInfoModel>> temp = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<AsoInfoModel>> aa : list) {
            temp.put(aa.getKey(), aa.getValue());
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values)